# Assigning calculation output to an N-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, iteration

I have a N one-dimensional arrays, `array1`, `array2`, ... `arrayN`. The arrays are not all the same length. I want to (1) pass every combination of values in each of the N arrays through a function `my_function()`, resulting in unique output values for each combination, which (2) ideally would then be stored in a second n-dimensional array `my_results`.

For context, `my_function()` does something like:

```
def my_function(data, a1, a2, ... aI, b1, b2, ... bJ):
    filename = f`file_{a1}_{a2}_..._{aI}`
    model = my_loadfunction(filename)

    new_model = my_model_manipulator(model, b1, b2, ... bJ)
    return my_probability_function(data, new_model)
```

where `N = I+J` and all `ai` and `bi` (that is, all `xi`) values are floats.

I can solve (1) trivially enough, through use of e.g. `itertools.product()`. But, for (2), I haven't found an elegant solution for yet, though. I can build an `np.array()` object that has the correct dimensionality, but the best I've been able to come up with to index over this array for storing the results of `my_function()` is a crude, N-nested `for iN,xN in enumerate(arrayN):` style arrangement:

```
for i1, x1 in enumerate(array1):
    for i2, x2 in enumerate(array2):
        ...
        for iN, xN in enumerate(arrayN):
            result = my_function(x1, x2, ..., xN)
            my_results[i1,i2, ... iN] = result
```

This is somewhat sluggish to run and, more annoyingly, hideous to look at and prone to problems of the "typo" variety. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Please post your actual attempt to solve this problem (as opposed to a description of it).

Comment: What are the `filenames` supposed to be like? Individual csv files so a comma separated list or what? can you provide it in your question

Comment: @OriYardenPhD I'm not sure how it's relevant to my question, but the file's names are formatted more or less exactly as shown. The files themselves are large, sprawling output files from another program, with a mix of numerical data and text. I have written a function elsewhere that extracts the interesting part (`model`), which is a 2-D array.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what specifically the operations `my_function` carries out so if you could provide a simple working example that conveys at least some of the context then I could provide a more apt, informed answer.

Although this is a really simple example of inputting `numpy` `array`s `a`, `b`, and `c` and passing the output through `my_function` to obtain `my_results`, the goals would be the same in that we want to flatten the `array`s and vectorize the operations carried out:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]])
b = np.array([[2.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]])
c = np.array([[3.0, 3.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0, 2.0], [2.0, 2.0, 3.0]])

def my_function(x1, x2, x3):
    return x1 * x2 * x3

my_results = my_function(a.reshape(-1), b.reshape(-1), c.reshape(-1)).reshape(a.shape)
print(my_results)
```

Outputs:

```
[[6. 0. 0.]
 [2. 0. 0.]
 [2. 0. 0.]]
```

Here the `array`s all have the same shape (which may not be in your case), among other things, etc. so providing a simple, workable example that accurately reflects most (or all) of the operations your actual `my_function` carries out could give me a better idea of the solution you're after.

Comment: I'll try to condense my function into something readable and provide that.